# Appcelerator take video screenshot for android environment return black image

Tags: android, titanium, screenshot, appcelerator

I am trying to get video screenshot as image for my image view. Below are my codes:

```
Ti.Media.takeScreenshot(function(e) {

    thisClass.Parent.VideoPlayer.Player.toImage();

    Ti.Media.saveToPhotoGallery(thisClass.Parent.VideoPlayer.Player.toImage()); 

    thisClass.AnimationVideoWrapper.setImage(thisClass.Parent.VideoPlayer.Player.toImage());
});
```

The problem is whenever I check my photo gallery and see from the image view, it turns out to be an image with black background color and not the video image. It supposed to capture the current playing video as thumbnail.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to take a screenshot from a video on device

Comment: Did you find that documented as a OS restriction somewhere @sebastian-klaus ?